# How to manage multi device (XBox 360 controller) LWJGL

Tags: java, lwjgl, xbox360

I make a 2D game in Java with LWjgl, and I use a XBox 360 controller for the input.
I want to add a second player, so I need to distinguish the two Xbox controllers.

But naturally, the two controller are like one only. If I press a bouton on controller number 1 or 2, the result is the same, I can't manage actions from each without imply the other.

Can someone help me pls ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to google next time. This is what I got searching "lwjgl xbox 360 controller". The first result is a youtube video. Go check it out, it was the solution for you (kinda, but you can get there).

EDIT

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jwFzrBiH8X0

Comment: I told in my answer that wasn't the solution you were looking for but you can get there by watching the video.

Comment: yeah, but i've already use the xboxController. Since I've find a solution, with a list<> of  xboxController, and an ID.